# count is not matching with egrep command in unix korn shell

Tags: shell, unix, count, grep, match

I'm trying to get the count of matches in unix korn shell but is not working, only is returning 1.
I have a variable that has the value "myfile-ddmmyy_HHMM", and what I'm doing is get the matches of it but is returning 1.

```
myfile="myfile-ddmmyy_HHMM"
echo $myfile | egrep -c "ddmmyy|HHMM"
```

it's suppossed that should return 2.

any idea?

Comment: You are just searching in the file name

Comment: Yes, it only are returning the first match.

Comment: I'm echo the variable due I have to replace "ddmmyy_HHMM" with the timestamp.

Comment: Why would you get 2?  There's only one line of input, so you'll only get at most 1 as the output count.  If you messed around with the GNU (or BSD) `grep` extension option `-o` (to output only the matching text, each match on its own line), then you'd get 2 returned.  Note that the use of the Korn shell is immaterial — what matters is the dialect of `grep` that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep` man page says:

```
-c, --count
         Only a count of selected lines is written to standard output.
```

So the result is expected, since it's supposed to print the number of matching **lines** (and you have *a single line*, which accidentally matches both your `egrep` patterns).